# Combined aggregate based on valid values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with this structure:

```
id  a1_l1   a2_l1   a3_l1   a1_l2   a2_l2   a3_l2
1   1       5       3       1       2       3
2   1       5       3       1       2       3
3   2       5       3       5       5       3
4   5       5       3       5       5       3
5   5       5       2           
6   5       5       2           
7   5       5       2           
8   2       5       2           
9   3       5       1           
10  3       5       1
```

I want to summarize in a table such that I get:

```
    l1  l2
a1  0.4 0.5
a2  1   0.5
a3  0   0
```

In which what I'm doing is counting how may times 5 was present divided by the number of valid responses, so that for example:

a1, l1 is equal to .4 as I have 4 values of 5 divided by 10. and a2, l1 equals .5 as I have 2 values of 5 divided by 4 valid responses per column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reshape to have a dataframe with MultiIndex, then perform a simple division of the (`sum` of the truthy values equal to 5) by not na. Finally, `unstack`:

```py
df2 = df.set_index('id')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.split('_', expand = True)
df2 = (df2.eq(5).sum()/df2.notna().sum()).unstack()
```

output:

```
     l1   l2
a1  0.4  0.5
a2  1.0  0.5
a3  0.0  0.0
```

Comment: made an edit ... some of the string functions offer the expand argument that turn to a MultiIndex if it is a pandas Index

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the `id` column `drop('id', axis=1)` as well instead of `set_index('id')`

1. calculate the percentage for each column using `(x == 5).sum() / x.notna().sum()`
2. reset the index to get a column we can work with
3. generate the 'a' and 'l' columns by splitting the index
4. pivot

```py
tmp = df.set_index('id').apply(lambda x: x.eq(5).sum()/x.notna().sum()).reset_index()
tmp[['a', 'l']] = tmp['index'].str.split('_', expand=True)


>>>
   index    0   a   l
0  a1_l1  0.4  a1  l1
1  a2_l1  1.0  a2  l1
2  a3_l1  0.0  a3  l1
3  a1_l2  0.5  a1  l2
4  a2_l2  0.5  a2  l2
5  a3_l2  0.0  a3  l2

tmp.drop('index', axis=1).pivot(index='a', columns='l').droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None).rename_axis(None, axis=1)

>>>
     l1   l2
a1  0.4  0.5
a2  1.0  0.5
a3  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `pd.wide_to_long`

```
s = pd.wide_to_long(df,['a1','a2','a3'],i='id',j = 'level',sep='_',suffix='\\w+')
out = s.eq(5).groupby(level=1).sum()
out = out.T.div(s.groupby(level=1).size())
out
level   l1   l2
a1     0.4  0.2
a2     1.0  0.2
a3     0.0  0.0
```

Comment: Nice use of `wide_to_long` ;) +1

Answer (score 1):

All the answers look equally complex, so I decided to run some benchmarks to help the OP make a decision.

I benchmarked each of the three solutions, each four times in succession, using IPython's `%timeit` magic. I used the OP's original 6x10 dataframe and a randomly-generated 100x10000 dataframe:

| Solution | Avg. time to run on OP's dataframe | Avg. time to run on 100x10000 dataframe |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874371/17242583) | **2.1 ms** | **42.88 ms (0.048 seconds)** |
| [Asish M.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874344/17242583) | 4.5 ms | 2,200 ms (2.2 seconds) |
| [BENY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69874353/17242583) | 13.3 ms | 1,772 ms (1.77 seconds) |

mozway's is *by far* the fastest.

**Congrats, [@mozway](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16343464/mozway)!**

---

#### Benchmark details for OP's dataset

```
# mozway
2.15 ms ± 29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.09 ms ± 17 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.1 ms ± 20.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
2.1 ms ± 16.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Asish M.
4.51 ms ± 18.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.49 ms ± 25.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.48 ms ± 20.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.51 ms ± 29.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# BENY
13.5 ms ± 419 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
13.3 ms ± 700 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
13.3 ms ± 285 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
13.3 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

#### Benchmark details for 100x10000 dataset

```
# BENY
1.77 s ± 11.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.77 s ± 13.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.76 s ± 13.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
1.79 s ± 32.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Asish M.
2.21 s ± 17.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.2 s ± 9.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.19 s ± 14.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
2.2 s ± 24.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# mozway
42.4 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
43.9 ms ± 498 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
43 ms ± 1.06 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
42.2 ms ± 1.18 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

##### Code used to generate 100x10000 dataset

```py
import random
import numpy as np
dct = {}
sz = 100
for x in range(sz):
    for y in range(sz):
        k = f'a{x}_l{y}'
        dct[k] = [random.choice(nums) for _ in range(sz)]
        dct[k].sort(key=lambda x: np.isnan(x)) # put nans at the end
dct['id'] = list(range(sz))
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

Comment: And how does it look when the data size is increased?

Comment: Check now @sammywemmy ;)

Comment: nice reminder that the less the number of rows to deal with the better. thanks for the benchmarks